# How to make your bot visible to specific users in a channel

Tags: botframework, bots, skype-for-business, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am working on a project that uses Microsoft Bot Framework. I have added Skype for Business channel to it. Now I want the bot to be discoverable by only selective users in the Skype for Business tenant. How to achieve that? If anyone can tell me about how to do the same, i.e. discoverable to selective people, inside Microsoft Teams - that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the functionality for selectively identifying Skype users is not supported, primarily for privacy reasons. The best option available would be to build a sign-in card (sample available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards)). The bot would be generally available, but only authorized persons would be able to use based on their login permissions.